# Jack and pulseaudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack

I want to run pulseaudio from startup to deal with system sounds etc and be able to run jack from qjackctl for use with audio applications (LMMS, ardour, rosegarden etc) I'm having issues when i start up, the sound applet does not allow me to control the volume. When I click sound preferences it says "waiting for sound system to respond" yet the sound still plays in rhythmbox etc.

Comment: It might be useful to know what exactly your sound setup is.  Do you have PA -> JACK -> ALSA permanently, or do you stop PA while you use JACK or ...?

Comment: Sorry not to be more precise, I'm very new to linux audio. Pulse runs at startup qjackctl kills off pulse "pulse-jack" and when i quit jack i restart pulse by "alt+f2 pulseaudio" ideally i want to get the that to be automated as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JACK breaks audio. How do I fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/729990/jack-breaks-audio-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for some reason pavucontrol had been uninstalled. just had to reinstall it.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the correct answer, but I'd recommend bringing up JACK only when you need it. Otherwise, things can get crazy with sound.

Comment: Thats what i'm doing at the moment however the problem is that when I start the computer (along with pulseaudio) the sound applet is no longer working. Its in the tray but all greyed out so I cannot use it

Comment: would you still recommend this today? with 20.04 out?

Comment: It's been a while since I've actively used JACK for anything, but unless I'm doing anything with music I'm unlikely to run JACK just for fun.