# JACK breaks audio. How do I fix it?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack

Audio was working fine until I tried to use qjackctl and qsynth to play a MIDI keyboard. I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19768/289003)* to setup the keyboard and it worked. But then I noticed other applications couldn't play audio (VLC, Rhythmbox, etc.). After a reboot it was fine again. And then I set up the keyboard and the problem was back. This went on for a few days and I thought I could live with it as it fixed itself on reboot. But then it didn't. I couldn't play audio, except via qsynth and the MIDI keyboard. Now not even that audio will play.

<sup>*Mostly. qjackctl wasn't exactly as described, but I believe I found all the mentioned controls.</sup>

I'm not sure what I really did with qjackctl, or how to get back where I was. I tried removing (with `apt-get purge`) qjackctl and qsynth but that didn't help. Now I've reinstalled qjackctl and have tried changing the which driver is used by qjackctl, all to on avail.

Ideally I'd like the MIDI keyboard to work, but far more important is getting the audio back like it should be.

I've checked all volumes using `alsamixer`.

I believe JACK makes pulseaudio stop (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603730/jack-audio-server-stopping-other-media-from-playing) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486513/jack-turns-off-other-sound), but I don't know how to stop jack and get it back to normal.

How can I make the audio work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop jackd by clicking "stop" in qjackctl  or running this command in a terminal:
`killall jackd`
then  if pulseaudio was stopped,  run this command:
`pulseaudio`
"Standard" audio should be back.
Pulseaudio and jackd can run  together installing **pulseaudio-module-jack**

EDIT  : **The real solution :**
     - try to install "pavucontrol" (pulse audio volume control)
and check in output tab that main audio device is selected.

Also check configuration tab: **This was the problem**: Nateowami changed  profile from  "Digital Output (S/PDIF)"  to "Analog Stereo Output" which solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but alas, I tried those. For the first one, `jackd: no process found` , and for the second, `E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.` I've also run `sudo service pulseaudio restart` and it says `stop: Unknown instance: 
pulseaudio start/running, process 10647`. I think JACK is stopped and pulseaudio is running. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: You can  try to install "pavucontrol"  (pulse audio volume control) and check in output tab  that main audio device is selected (also check configuration tab) . Also, in alsamixer, press F6 and check that you really control main soundcard (as most modern pc have another soundcard in hdmi  output)

Comment: pavucontrol output tab says "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)" and is the only one shown (at the bottom it's set to show all output devices).  Port is set to "Digital Output (S/PDIF)", which is the only option. When I play music in Rhythmbox  both the Playback and Output Devices tabs in pavucontrol show audio volume rising and falling as the music plays. I tried muting and un-muting in both tabs.

Comment: Then I went to the Configuration tab and switched the profile from "Digital Output (S/PDIF)" or "Digital Output (S/PDIF) + Analog Stereo Input" (can't remember which) to "Analog Stereo Output". Viola! It works! Thank you! I still don't know what caused the problem...

Comment: I thought about accepting, but I don't think the answer is really the answer to the problem. +1 though.